# Pine script divergence indicator display problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using this divergence indicator which is working fine when it is calculated for the macd but when I use the stochastic it displays the bearish divergence fine but not the bullish. Can anybody see what is preventing it from displaying properly.

```
macd = ta.ema(close,12) - ta.ema(close,26)
stoch = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, 8), 3)


lbR = 5
lbL = 5
rangeUpper = 60
rangeLower = 5
plotBull = true
plotBear = true
bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

osc = macd
//osc = stoch

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1]) and 
osc[lbR] < 0
// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound
plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, 
color=bullCond ? bullColor : color.new(color.white, 100))
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish
// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1]) and osc[lbR] > 0
// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)
bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound
plot(phFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish', linewidth=2, 
color=bearCond ? bearColor : color.new(color.white, 100))
```

Comment: I mean, did you even try to debug it? What is the issue? How is it working now? Throwing out some random code and telling us it doesn't work does not really help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macd final range is normalized around zero so your primary condition of HL & LH is:

```
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1]) and osc[lbR] < 0
oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1]) and osc[lbR] > 0
```

But when you change the source from Macd to Stochastic you should consider its final range too, The Stochastic range is 0:100 and normalize around 50 so:

```
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1]) and osc[lbR] < 50
oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1]) and osc[lbR] > 50
```

replace 0 with 50 and enjoy from Stochastic result.